# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for class

Tags: android, retrofit2, moshi

Recently I switched to MoshiConverterFactory from GSONConverterFactory. Every thing s working fine except the one call. Like other API calls here also I am using @Body annotation but I am getting this error 
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for class

my request class :

```
data class DemoRequest(
val emailId: String? = null,
val demoData: List<DemoDomain?>? = null,
val userName: String? = null
```

)

One more thing here to mention that with GSONConverterFactory it is working fine but as I switched to MoshiConverterFactory it is throwing error.

retrofitVersion = '2.3.0'

service interface:

```
@POST("call/api")
fun sendToServer(@Body request: DemoRequest):retrofit2.Call<RemoteResponse>

val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()
```

UPDATE-------------
I was sending Date object in request so I need to use custom adapter and it is working fine now

Answer (score 1):

Did you remember to change to `MoshiConverterFactory` when you build Retrofit?

`Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(...).addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create()).build()`

Also, the latest version of Retrofit is 2.5.0 so you could try upgrading and make sure your converter is also the same version.

Comment: Other server calls are working fine. Only this call causing the issue.